# What's an easy way to export threejs-generated model to 3dmax and Archicad?

Tags: three.js

My online configurator based on three.js generates some model. I need to provide export abilities for designers and architects. I guess the most demanded soft is 3dmax and Archicad.

How to export? glTF does not supported by 3dmax. OBJ export? I cant find reference or example.

Comment: Do you have to export just the geometry information or material data as well? If only the geometry is relevant, you might want to give [OBJExporter](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_exporter_obj) a try.

Comment: Greate. Thanks. Geometry is enough.